# Understanding np.where() in the context of Logistic Regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am currently studying the Deep Learning specialization taught on Coursera by Andrew Ng. In the first assignment, I have to define a prediction function, and wanted to know if my alternative solution is as valid as the actual solution.

Please let me know if my understanding of the np.where() function is correct as I have commented on this in the code under "ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION COMMENTS". Also, it would be much appreciated if my understanding under the "ACTUAL SOLUTION COMMENTS" could be checked as well.

The alternate solution that uses np.where() also works when I try to increase the number of examples/inputs in X the current amount (m = 3), to 4, to 5, and so on.

Let me know what you think, and if both solutions are just as good as the other! Thanks.

```
def predict(w, b, X):
    '''
    Predict whether the label is 0 or 1 using learned logistic regression parameters (w, b)

    Arguments:
    w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
    b -- bias, a scalar
    X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)

    Returns:
    Y_prediction -- a numpy array (vector) containing all predictions (0/1) for the examples in X
    '''

    m = X.shape[1]
    Y_prediction = np.zeros((1,m))    # Initialize Y_prediction as an array of zeros 
    w = w.reshape(X.shape[0], 1)

    # Compute vector "A" predicting the probabilities of a cat being present in the picture
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, X) + b)   # Note: The shape of A will always be a (1,m) row vector
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    for i in range(A.shape[1]):       # for i in range(# of examples in A = # of examples in our set)

        # Convert probabilities A[0,i] to actual predictions p[0,i]
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 4 lines of code)
        Y_prediction[0, i] = 1 if A[0, i] > 0.5 else 0

        ''' 
        ACTUAL SOLUTION COMMENTS: 

        The above reads as:

        Change/update the i-th value of Y_prediction to 1 if the corresponding i-th value in A is > 0.5. 
        Otherwise, change/update the i-th value of Y_prediction to 0. 

        '''


        ''' 
        ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION COMMENTS:

        To condense this code, you could delete the for loop and Y_prediction var from the top, 
        and then use the following one line: 

        return np.where(A > 0.5, np.ones((1,m)), np.zeros((1,m))) 

        This reads as: 
        Given the condition > 0.5, return np.ones((1,m)) if True, 
        or return np.zeros((1,m)) if False. 

        Another way to understand this is as follows:
        Tell me where in the array A, entries satisfies the condition A > 0.5,
        At those positions, give me np.ones((1,m)), otherwise, give me 
        np.zeros((1,m))

        '''
        ### END CODE HERE ###

    assert(Y_prediction.shape == (1, m))

    return Y_prediction

w = np.array([[0.1124579],[0.23106775]])
b = -0.3
X = np.array([[1.,-1.1,-3.2],[1.2,2.,0.1]])
print(sigmoid(np.dot(w.T, X) + b))
print ("predictions = " + str(predict(w, b, X)))   # Output gives 1,1,0 as expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alternative approach seems fine. As a remark, I'll add that you don't even need the `np.ones` and `np.zeros`, you can just specify directly the integers `0` and `1`. When using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), as long as `X` and `y` (the values to replace according to the condition) and the same condition are broadcastable, it should work fine.
Here's a simple example:

```
y_pred = np.random.rand(1,6).round(2)
# array([[0.53, 0.54, 0.68, 0.34, 0.53, 0.46]])
np.where(y_pred> 0.5, np.ones((1,6)), np.zeros((1,6)))
# array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

And using integers:

```
np.where(y_pred> 0.5,1,0)
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

As per your comments on how the function works it is indeed working as you describe. Perhaps just instead of `To condense this code`, I'd argue that using numpy makes it more efficient, and also intelligible in this case.

Comment: Thanks! And oh yeah, numpy is a godsend! This might be a silly question but I tried to implement "return np.where(A > 0.5, 1, 0)" as you suggested and the outcome is "predictions = [[1 1 0]]" rather than "predictions = [[1. 1. 0.]]" . Could you tell me the significance of the dot after each value in the array? Also, np.where doesn't replace the original array does it?

Comment: The dot distinguishes floats from ints. Read on data types if that is not clear.  If you want floats use dots `np.where(y_pred> 0.5,1.,0.)`. No, np.where does not replace it, it creates a new array @user13443549

Comment: Lol, I knew it was probably just a float/int deal. Hence, why I prefaced my question with "this might be silly". Thanks a ton! :)